# Code works fine but I can't understand what it prints

Tags: c++

So I'm reading C++ Primer (5th edition) and this is the example code they give to explain the while statement:

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int sum = 0, val = 1;
    // keep executing the while as long as val is less than or equal to 10
    while (val <=10) {
        sum += val; // assigns sum + val to sum
        ++val; // add 1 to val
    }
    std::cout << "Sum of 1 to 10 inclusive is " << sum << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And this is the program in the Command Line prompt:

[image: program]

I just can't understand where the 55 came from..

Isn't it supposed to be:

```
sum = 0
var = 1
sum = 0 + 1
var = 1 + 1
-snip-
sum = 6
var = 4
```

So shouldn't it print 6?
I'm really confused.

Comment: `1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10 = 55`. Why do you stop at 4?

Comment: Oh, I just got it, it asks for the var to be 10 and not the sum, damn I was almost having a headache because I felt so stupid, I might actually am.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10 = 55`

Answer (score 1):

What it does is:

1. initializes val to 1
2. increments val till it reaches 10 in each iteration
3. this val is added to sum in each iteration
4. after 10 iterations, this sums up to 55.

Still not clear, use a debugger and check each step.

Comment: User rodrigo provided the answer in the comments section.Thank for your time, it was me just being stupid, no errors at all!